Transitive groups with fixed-point free elements of prime power order
A well-known result of Fein, Kantor and Schacher says that if $G$ is a finite group which acts transitively on a set $X$, then $G$ contains an element of prime power order without fixed letters. Unfortunately, they use the classification of finite simple groups (CFSG).
Since I take it that there still isn't a CFSG-free proof of this result (?), I wondered if extra properties could lead to the same conclusion.
So suppose that $G$, finite, acts $2$-transitively on the set $X$. Does there exist a CFSG-free proof of the fact that there is an element of prime power order in $G$ which fixes precisely one letter ?

By "letter", do you mean an element of $X$?

@MichaelHardy: yes.
